# How to connect to the database using .env inside typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I tried to connect the database using `ormconfig.js` and create `.env` but I get an error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js: 1141: 16) ORMCONFIG.JS
>
> errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 3000,   fatal: true }

```
module.exports = {
"type": process.env.TYPEORM_CONNECTION,
"url" : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
"host": process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
"port": process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
"username": process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
"password": process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
"database": process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
"synchronize": process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE,
"logging": process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING,
"entities": [
   "dist/entity/**/*.ts"
],
"migrations": [
   "dist/migration/**/*.ts"
],
"subscribers": [
   "dist/subscriber/**/*.ts"
],
"cli": {
   "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
   "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
   "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
}}
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL= http://root:@localhost:3000
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = mysql
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME = root
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = 
TYPEORM_DATABASE = login_controlaccess
TYPEORM_PORT = 3000
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
```

index.js

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import * as express from "express";
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as helmet from  'helmet';
import routes from './routers';
dotenv.config();
const PORT= process.env.TYPEORM_PORT || 3000;


createConnection().then(async () => {

    // create express app
       const app = express();
    //middleware
      app.use(cors());
      app.use(helmet());
      app.use(express.json());
     //ROuter
      app.use('/', routes); 
    // start express server
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`server running in port ${PORT}`));


    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `dotenv.config()` after you import from `typeorm`, you probably need to do that first.

Also, note that you need to configure those environment variables in either the `.env` *or* the `ormconfig.js`, you have included them in both.